# Simple Binding does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, bin

I've got that simple Data Binding in a Windows 8.1 App using C#/XAML as well as the MVVM-Light-Toolkit and it does not work. I want to Display a list that lists the time from 6 o'clock in the morning to 6 o'clock the next day. Here is the relevant code:

```
public class DayViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<DateTime> _TimesList = null;   

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the TimesList property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> TimesList
    {
        get
        {
            return _TimesList;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_TimesList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(TimesListPropertyName);
            _TimesList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(TimesListPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public void CreateTimes()
    {
        TimesList = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            TimesList.Add(DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(6 + i));
        }
    }
}
```

Now the binding in XAML EDIT: The full hierarchy is shown now:

```
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <ListView Grid.Column="0"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Day.TimesList, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                                    ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource DayCalendarTimesItemTemplate}}">
                        </ListView>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And the template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DayCalendarTimesItemTemplate">
    <Grid Height="80">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Date}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Well I guess that I am binding to the wrong object in the TextBox? I am really frustrated about that problem - I just can't figure out what is wrong here.

EDIT: Information about the Locator:

The locator is the standard locator provided by the MVVM-Light Toolkit:

Here is the Class with the registration of that ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DayViewViewModel>();
    }

    public DayViewViewModel Day
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DayViewViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

The locator is instantiated in the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
    [...]
    </ResourceDictionary>      
</Application.Resources>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

FunkyPeanut

Comment: did you try `<TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>`?

Comment: Does it display list of empty `TextBoxes` or nothing at all?

Comment: Nothing. I even tried removing the template and there was still nothing displayed.

Comment: That changes things. What is `Locator`? Where and how do you define this resource?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I will post the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that problem.

The ListView I posted above was inside a DataTemplate itself. I kind of forgot to give that information. Once I removed it from the template the binding worked fine.